# Media files not loading in email in Django

Tags: python, django, apache, email, django-staticfiles

I have a Django project deployed on Apache web server. I am serving my media files in folder `/var/www/media/`. My media files load okay when I am on my web application.

I have a feature which sends email to different people. In that email those media files should load, but they show 404 error in console.

This is what I added in my **apache2.conf** file:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/search/egeirn/project/egeirn/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /home/search/egeirn/project:/home/search/virtualenvs/egerin/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Alias /media/ /var/www/media/
Alias /static/ /var/www/static/

<Directory /var/www/static>
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/media>
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/search/egeirn/project/egeirn>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

This is my **base.py** file:

```
...
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/var/www/media/'
...
```

This is my **production.py** file which is loaded in **manage.py** and **wsgi.py**:

```
from .base import *

DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['iro.egerin.com']

MEDIA_URL = 'http://iro.egerin.com/media/'
```

Please tell what I should do to load my media files out of the application like in email?

*Just to give an idea this is the error in the console:*

[image]

Comment: did you set the media urls in the project urls.py

Answer (score 0):

You have missed to add your server name in the template where you have added the media files.
You image element should be something like:

```
<img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{path_of_image}}" />
```

You have missed the media_url in the template.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added the media urls in your project urls.py

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
                            {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': False}),)
```

set the MEDIA_ROOT in the project settings.py , then directly you can access the Images in the template using `.url` ( `{{instace.prodimage.url }}`)

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the purpose of adding media urls in urls.py?

Comment: to read the media file path from the database, ( once you uploaded the media file to the application , the file go to the media folder which you mention the model creation and the path is stored into the model field)